# Multiple column names does not work in select from subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY c1.Id) as [rank], 
    C1.Id, C1.Name, 
    P2.Id, P2.Name, P2.CategoryId  
FROM 
    Category C1  
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Product P2 ON C1.Id = P2.Id
```

So this will return 4 categories that will be replicated 'N' times as many products as there is. I want to be able to apply a "Skip and Take" method over the categories however with the query returning a N+1 this is not possible via the normal means.

I'd like to be able to use `DENSE_RANK` to be able to do this, however this is not possible as the calculation from `DENSE_RANK` cannot be used inside a WHERE.

I came up with this SQL:

```
SELECT  
    v.*
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY c1.Id) as [rank], 
         C1.Id, C1.Name, 
         P2.Id, P2.Name, P2.CategoryId  
     FROM 
         Category C1  
     LEFT OUTER JOIN 
         Product P2 ON C1.Id = P2.Id) v
WHERE 
    v.rank > 0 AND v.rank < 4
```

However I get a compile time error of:

> The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 'v'.

This was not a problem with the original query, both product and category have `Id` on them but the first query executed and returned the expected result. This all of a sudden becomes a problem with the second query and I am unsure as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if you add `where ... and v.id = 2`, then which column does it filter on? You can alias the columns using `as` prior to bringing them into your result set.

```
SELECT v.*
FROM (
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY c1.Id) as [rank], 
    C1.Id as CId, C1.Name as CName, 
    P2.Id as Pid, P2.Name as PName, P2.CategoryId  
    FROM Category C1  
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Product P2 
        ON C1.Id = P2.Id
  ) v
WHERE v.rank > 0 AND v.rank < 4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, both we're right but your extra comments made it click for me and realise of course that is the reason

Answer (score 2):

The column names need to be unique.  Use aliases:

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY c1.Id) as [rank], 
       C1.Id as c_id, C1.Name as c_name, 
       P2.Id as p_id, P2.Name as p_name, P2.CategoryId
FROM Category C1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Product P2 
     ON C1.Id = P2.Id;
```

This can then work as a subquery, CTE, or view.